# MSBuild SonarQube Runner: "Failed to locate the code coverage command line tool" still with version 1.0.1

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am trying to use *MSBuild SonarQube Runner* to have my TFS-builds run the Sonar analysis.

I have configured the tool to work with our sonar Server according to this [manual](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/releases/download/1.1.0/SonarQube-Setup-Guide-For-Net-Users-V-1-1-0.pdf). Actually I can start an analysis by building manually via console on my local machine. Additionally, I installed the tool on our build server and when I run it via Visual Studio, I’ll get the error *"Failed to locate the code coverage command line tool"*.

I already found out that the CodeCoverage.exe is needed, but only given with installing an Enterprise version of Visual Studio on the server. I also read that in version 1.0.1, this issue should be fixed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308008/integrating-sonarqube-into-tfs-2013-failed-to-locate-the-code-coverage-command) and in the changelog [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-130) is also mentioned as fixed).

I exchanged the old *MSBuild SonarQube Runner* with the `version 1.0.1`, but with building on the TFS in Visual Studio and adding the command lines to run *`MSBuild SonarQube Runner v1.0.1`*, I still get the error *"Failed to locate the code coverage command line tool"*.

I also have Visual Studio 2015 Professional installed on the build mashine.

How can I fix this issue without needing an Enterprise version of Visual Studio providing the *CodeCoverage.exe*?

Answer (score 1):

Code Coverage still requires Visual Studio Enterprise in the 2015 version (see [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx)).

The [bug](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-130) you referred to fixed an issue in version 1.0 that meant that analysis would fail if the code coverage tool could not be found. Analysis will no longer fail if the code coverage tool was not found, but it doesn't change the requirement to have to VS Enterprise installed if you want to use the Microsoft code coverage tools.

Comment: And is is possible to deactivate the CodeCoverage and still have the MSBuild SonarQube Runner trigger the SonarQubeAnalysis on a TFS-Build?
Because for me the Build still fails and I do not get Results shown in SonarQube.
How could i fix this?

Comment: With v1.0.1, yes: if the code coverage tool cannot be found then analysis should continue without error-ing. What error are you getting?

Comment: Ok the error *"Failed to locate the code coverage command line tool"* is not sown to me anymore after I inserted the Dynamic Code Coverage Tools folder i got from an collegue at the right spot.
Even after deleting it again i don't get the following error:

Comment: 10:45:39  The sonar-runner did not complete successfully
 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
 Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)`

Comment: And the log says the following:

Comment: WriteSonarQubeProjectData:
         Directory "C:\Builds\2\dsCodeFormatterDotnNet\dsCodeFormatterCSharp\.sonarqube\out\\dsCodeFormatterCSharp__AnyCPU_Debug_635786019177014666" doesn't exist. Skipping.
         Creating directory "C:\Builds\2\dsCodeFormatterDotnNet\dsCodeFormatterCSharp\.sonarqube\out\\dsCodeFormatterCSharp__AnyCPU_Debug_635786019177014666".\dsCodeFormatterCSharp.sln" (default targets).

Build succeeded.

Comment: But the log also says Build succeeded. and     2 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Comment: How can it be the log tells me it was sucessfull when TFS and visual Studio tell me the build failed?